# __NSStackBlock__ isEqualToString: issue

Tags: objective-c, nsnotificationcenter

I am experimenting with [this code](https://github.com/KieranLafferty/KLNoteViewController).
In one of `viewController`'s I am using next snippet:

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView1 shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    if([text isEqualToString:@"\n"])
    {
        [textView resignFirstResponder];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

I found in web to dismissing the keyboard by pressing `returnButton`. It works well when I am calling it from this `viewController`. In root `KLNoteViewController` I am adding notification in handle state changes-method:

```
- (void) setState:(KLControllerCardState)state animated:(BOOL) animated
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"refresh" object:self];

    if (animated)
    {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:self.noteViewController.cardAnimationDuration animations:^{
            [self setState:state animated:NO];
        }];
        return;
    }
    //Full Screen State
    if (state == KLControllerCardStateFullScreen)
    {
        [self expandCardToFullSize: animated];
        [self setYCoordinate: 0];
    }
    //Default State
    else if (state == KLControllerCardStateDefault)
    {
        [self shrinkCardToScaledSize: animated];
        [self setYCoordinate: originY];
    }
    //Hidden State - Bottom
    else if (state == KLControllerCardStateHiddenBottom)
    {
        //Move it off screen and far enough down that the shadow does not appear on screen
        [self setYCoordinate: self.noteViewController.view.frame.size.height + abs(self.noteViewController.cardShadowOffset.height)*3];
    }
    //Hidden State - Top
    else if (state == KLControllerCardStateHiddenTop)
    {
        [self setYCoordinate: 0];
    }

    //Notify the delegate of the state change (even if state changed to self)
    KLControllerCardState lastState = self.state;
    //Update to the new state
    [self setState:state];
    //Notify the delegate
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(controllerCard:didChangeToDisplayState:fromDisplayState:)]) {
        [self.delegate controllerCard:self
              didChangeToDisplayState:state fromDisplayState: lastState];
    }
}
```

and add adding observer:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(dismissKeyboard) name:@"refresh" object:nil];
```

in every `viewController`s `-viewDidLoad`. So when this observer is used with `UITextField` everything works fine, in `viewController` when I am using `UIText View` I have crash with log:

> [**NSStackBlock** isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance 0xbfffd228

I searched in web but found only two links with explanation of what is the `NSStackBlock` is and they are not informative well for me to solve the problem. Can somebody explain what it can be?

Comment: Somehow you're passing an `__NSStackBlock__` instance into the `-textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText:` function as the last parameter (`text`).

Comment: This doesn’t really have anything to do with `NSStackBlock`; it’s a memory error. Somehow the `text` parameter is getting released prematurely or something like that. Does your project use ARC?

Comment: please check update. I am added Method at what I am post notification

Comment: @bdesham, yes I am using arc

Comment: @AdamRosenfield, thanks! But I can't understand how it can be possible